"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch" when using Selenium for Electron app in Robot framework
so currently we are using Electron for our application and I am trying to use the selenium library for it in Robot framework but I encountered 2 errors.
In my StartElectron.robot file, I have these:
*** Settings ***
Library    RPA.Browser.Selenium
Library    RPA.JSON

*** Variables ***
${portNumber}=    9515

*** Keywords ***
Start WebDriver Service
    ${port}             Convert To Integer      ${portNumber}
    ${service}=         Evaluate        sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].chrome.service      sys
    ${service}          CallMethod      ${service}      Service         C:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe     port=${port}
    Call Method         ${service}      start

Open Electron App
    ${options}=         Evaluate        sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()     sys
     Call Method         ${options}      add_argument                        --remote-debugging-port\=7070
    Call Method         ${options}      add_argument                        --no-sandbox
    ${options.binary_location}    Set Variable    C:/Users/Mozi/AppData/Local/Programs/dev2/dev2.exe
    Create Webdriver    Remote          command_executor=127.0.0.1:${portNumber}     options=${options}


Enter username
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    id:login-username   
    Click Element    id:login-username
    Input Text    id:login-username    dev2_encoder_1


Then on my TC1_Login.robot:
*** Settings ***
Library    RPA.Browser.Selenium
Library    RPA.JSON
Resource    ../../StartElectron1.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Login Encoder user
    Start WebDriver Service
    Open Electron App
    Enter username 

When I try to run my test case, electron app will open but I always receive this error:
[27464:0812/143225.154:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch", source: file:///C:/Users/Mozi/AppData/Local/Programs/dev2/resources/app.asar/build/service-worker.js (0)
and the
NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: window was already closed error.
The no such window error I think might be because whenever our electron app starts, it will start with a window that has the company logo then it will close the window and open again a new window quickly for the login page (this happens within 1-2 seconds), so I tried the built in Sleep and also Wait Until Page Contains Element    id:login-username but I still receive the no such window error.
Any ideas on how I can resolve these errors? All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!
